# Problems making Afl-fuzzer using BinUtils on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, command-line, software-installation, binutils

Aim:

- I am trying to setup and run `Afl Fuzzer` ([link](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/)), as part of following an online course.

Info:

- I'm running `Ubuntu 14.04` on dvd.
- In the video the teacher uses the `BinUtils` `2.25` package, and I chose to use the latest version `2.26`.
- I don't have much experience with compiling / making software.

Steps I followed:

- Downloaded the latest version of `BinUtils` to the Desktop
  (`/home/ubuntu/Desktop`)
- Unpacked BinUtils folder using `tar` via Terminal.
- Used `make` to try to create the program in the unpacked folder on the Desktop, which I think worked.
- Downloaded the latest version of `afl-latest.tgz` from [here](http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/afl/releases/afl-latest.tgz) to `/home/ubuntu/`.
- Unpacked afl-latest.tgz using `tar` via Terminal.
- Used `make` to try to create the program in `/home/ubuntu/afl-2.08b`, which I think worked.

Problems:

- The output using `ls -a` of that folder is significantly different to the output shown on the video (ie I don't have all of the files that the Teacher has shown) after `make` has been run.
- Get error `bash: ./configure: No such file or directory` when in the folder `/home/ubuntu/afl-2.08b/`, and try to run the following command: `CC=afl-gcc ./config`. The `afl-gcc.c` file exists in the folder. Do I need to try `./configure --prefix=/home/ubuntu/afl-2.08b/` ?
- `Cannot compile executables` error message.

What I've tried:

- Tried to find out which folder for Binutils I should be in for doing the `make`. It's not clear from the online course, and there are several similarly named folders. Searches have not been fruitful thus far.
- Posted question re the BinUtils folder on Course chat area for the video in question.
- Sent email asking where BinUtils folder is to the course provider.
- Read the `Readme` file for `BinUtils`.
- Read the `Readme` file for `afl-2.08b`.
- Googled `cannot compile executables`

I wasn't sure whether this is my inexperience of using Ubuntu terminal commands, or trying to follow unclear instructions.

What I haven't tried yet:

- Installed latest version of gcc

Update:

I got it working in the end. I think I should have been running ./configure when in the /binutils folder.

I also forgot to do:

1) chmod 777 -R on each of the folders 
2) sudo make install

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a particular reason to build `afl` from source, I would recommend using Ubuntu Xenial (16.04), which [comes with `afl` in the repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/afl). Just run this:

```
sudo apt-get install afl
```

and now `afl-gcc` will be in your `$PATH`, so you won't get the `No such file or directory` error.

Next, install the dependencies required to build `binutils`:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep binutils
```

Now you can download and build the source to `binutils` into the current working directory with a single command, no `sudo` required:

```
apt-get source -b binutils
```

This will take a while to download and build. It won't be the latest sources, but that should not be necessary for fuzzing.

Once they are finished building, you will be in much better shape for recompiling with `afl-gcc` and starting the fuzzing process.

Comment: This will be useful for those with a good connection. The one I use is temperamental so have to do manual install via removable media.

Comment: Do you need a good connection to install `afl` or to download the source code for `binutils`? The `afl` package is less than 100 kBytes.

Comment: Also, you can install dependencies to a flash drive as described here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline

Comment: If you mean to download Ubuntu itself, torrents are good for a temperamental connection. https://ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads